# Get file path from dialog box and print to NSLog (Cocoa Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, file, osx-yosemite

I have a project that opens a file browser and when I select and open a file, I would like to print the file path for testing.

Here is my .main file:

```
@implementation SaveMenuCntroller

- (IBAction)askUserForImage:(id)sender {
    NSOpenPanel*    panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

    // Let the user select any images supported by
    // the NSImage class.
    NSArray* imageTypes = [NSImage imageTypes];
    [panel setAllowedFileTypes:imageTypes];

    [panel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result){
        if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
        }
    }];
}

@end
```

Anyone have experience with this that could help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
NSLog(@"selected file: %@", panel.URLs);
```

The `URLs` property is an array to support multiple selection. You could also do:

```
NSLog(@"selected file: %@", panel.URLs.firstObject);
```

And, finally, if you really want a path string instead of a URL, do:

```
NSLog(@"selected file: %@", [panel.URLs.firstObject path]);
```